# Passing variable to an inner function

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

```
function getSsrBandAid(ssn,id) {    
   DWREngine._execute(_ajaxConfig._cfscriptLocation, null, 'getSsrBandAid', ssn, doQueryResults); //calling method in decRequest.cfc    
   function doQueryResults(t){  
     xmlT = loadXMLString(t);  
     alert(ssn);            
   }
}
```

Trying to pass ssn to doQueryResults() function.
I have tried to this doQueryResults(t,ssn) but it doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any errors? Because at first glance the code looks fine. Maybe it is down to the DWREngine object of _execute function?

Comment: I get an "undefined" error. Is there any other way to pass it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ECMA-/Javascript has a static (lexical) scope. It also has the feature, that an "innerContext" closes over an "outerContext".

To make a long long story short, your `doQueryResults()` will copy the **parent Scope** (which is getSsrBandAid). That includes the **Activation object** which holds the arguments.

So if `alert(ssn);`  is undefined, it is also undefined when calling `getSsrBandAid()`.

Comment: I am passing ssn value to getSsrBandAid(ssn).

Comment: @Noe: what is the value of `ssn` when `getSsrBandAid` is called?

Comment: When I call getSsrBandAid(ssn) I pass an ssn to it, if i do an alert(SSN) before it gets to doQueryResults() I get a the right value.

Comment: @Noe: this is actually not possible. You don't need that `t` variable, you can just access `ssn` in your inner function. See this example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/sB9Jx/

Comment: I do need t variable it is the returning result:  DWREngine._execute(_ajaxConfig._cfscriptLocation, null, 'getSsrBandAid', ssn, doQueryResults);

Comment: @Noe: the result of what? where is `t` declared?

Comment: doQueryResults is a ajaxCFC function for ColdFusion and it is returning a result from a cfc page.

Comment: If `t` is what's returned from your ajaxCFC call, have you dumped that out with `console.log()` to see how it looks?

Comment: yes its in xml format. I get that with no problem. I just want to pass the ssn to the function.

Comment: I'm just getting the ssn from the input box. Thanks